# Linq to List: Is there a way to include all the columns after applying a groupby on list

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a list that is getting its values from the database and then this is converted to a datatable, but before doing that i want to apply groupby on the list and get all the columns instead of just a key and a value. After a new list is created using groupby datatable does not show all the columns instead it has only two columns which says capacity and count.

```
var groupedResults = Results.GroupBy(x => x.PROJECT_ID)
                            .Select(y => y.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

Results is a list which contains around 14 columns or keys in this case with all project related properties project name, id etc. When I use Results and convert that to datatable I do not have any issue but when I use groupedResults list as shown above and convert that to a datatable it does not have all the 14 columns and an exception is raised as column not found. Is there a way to select all the keys as in original list.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: have you tried with SelectMany?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi is there a way to select all

Comment: you could join it again with the Results to get all the columns

Comment: Are you sure you want to use GroupBy? Don't you just want OrderBy? The result of your query now is a list of lists, grouped by Project Id. The items in every group should still contain all properties of Results though.

Comment: @mstaessen I have my datatable as attached to the question, it has to be grouped beacuse it changes only on one column.

Comment: What is the point in grouping by every column? Are you trying to avoid duplicates or count duplicates?

Comment: @sgmoore i am trying to merge the columns with same data for example if you see the table in the above question for each project name, id and date are same except for p_bo_id. I want this to be shown on UI something like this : 1 test 12/1/2016

Comment: @sgmoore now its shown twice on UI instead of once

Comment: Sounds like you don't want grouping by want to do something like `... = Results.Select(y => new { y.Project_id, y.p_name, y.p_date}).Distinct().ToList()` and yes you do have to explicitly name each column apart from the one that you are ignoring.

Comment: @sgmoore this works perfect, now this gets the distinct values only if I do not select p_bo_id in the new selected list...thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wwith something like:

```
var groupedResults = Results.GroupBy(x => new {x.PROJECT_ID, obj = x})
                            .Select(y => y.Key.obj.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: i tried this but gets all the rows as in Results, does not groupby

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var e = Results.GroupBy(x => x.PROJECT_ID) .Select(y =>new { ProjectId = y.Key,
Count=y.Count()})
.Join(Results,x=>x.ProjectId,y=>y.PROJECT_ID,(x1,y1) => new 
{x1.ProjectId,x1.Count,y1.Col1,y1.Col2 /* Add all columns you need */} )
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: is there a way to get all the columns after groupby with out writing each column name, the reason is I have too many columns..

Comment: @Agasthya I am not sure if that is possible when you need a flattened type as output

Comment: while selecting the columns  needed you are using x1 and yi, i thought y1 points to all the columns in it...is there any reason to use both of them

Comment: @Agasthya x1 refers to the projected grouped list which has only two columns projectId and count. y1 refers to the original results.